# NSNumber literals & fixed width integer types

Tags: objective-c

I have three fixed width integer types:

```
typedef int16_t TABCellManagedDataKey;
typedef int16_t TABCellManagedDataIndex;
typedef int32_t TABCellManagedDataKeyWithIndex;
```

And this is the code where they're being used:

```
TABCellManagedDataKeyWithIndex keyWithIndex = key << 16 | index;
[[self managedModel] setObject:model forKey:@(keyWithIndex)];
```

With the new `@()` syntax for `NSNumber` literals, is it safe to do the following instead?

```
[[self managedModel] setObject:model forKey:@(key << 16 | index)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That is fine. `@(N)` is the same as `[NSNumber numberWithX:N]`.

Comment: I use `@()` in both cases. The difference is that in the first case I define the variable as `TABCellManagedDataKeyWithIndex` which is exactly 32 bits long.

Comment: @() infers the type from the argument.

Comment: I see. And is the argument 32 bit? It's not explicitly declared; it's just `@(key << 16 | index)` where both `key` and `index` are 16 bit.

Comment: Yes, but 16 is `int`, so they will be cast to `int` to match up.